# Scanf перестает считывать данные после некорректного ввода

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток! Написал программу которая разменивает сумму по 1,3,5 монет. Написал защиту от некорректного ввода. После тестов обнаружил, что если ввести символ, а не число, то при попытке заново ввести другое число scanf что то считывает из потока. Пытался очистить входной поток с помощью fflush но это не дало никаких результатов. Помогите исправить эту проблему! Заранее спасибо!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int amount1, amount3, amount5, numberOfVariation = 0;
    int number;
    int flag, repeatFlag;

    do
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter the number: ");
        flag = scanf("%d", &number);

        if (flag)
        {
            for (amount1 = 0; amount1 <= number; amount1++)
                for (amount3 = 0; amount3 * 3 <= number; amount3++)
                    for (amount5 = 0; amount5 * 5 <= number; amount5++)
                        if ((amount1 + amount3 * 3 + amount5 * 5) == number)
                        {
                            numberOfVariation++;
                            printf("%2d) 1 cents = %2d, 3 cents = %2d, 5 cents = %2d\n",numberOfVariation,amount1, amount3, amount5);
                        }
        }

        else printf("Uncorrect input data!\n");

        printf("Do you want to use this programm again? (y/n)\n");
        do
        {
            switch (_getch())
            {
            case 'y': repeatFlag = 1; break;
            case 'n': repeatFlag = 0; break;
            default:        
                    printf("Uncorrect input data! Try again!\n");
                    repeatFlag = 2;
                    break;
            }
        } while (repeatFlag == 2);
    } while (repeatFlag == 1);

    printf("\nThanks for using!\n");
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fflush(stdin) - UB (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170435/8491726). `if (flag)` после scanf вообще непонятно. scanf может вернуть 1 при удачном парсинге и EOF при конце потока. И в обоих случаях Вы выполняете условие.

Answer (score 2):

```
    else
    {
        printf("Uncorrect input data!\n");
        while(getc(stdin) != '\n');
    }
```

Comment: Я думаю, вы хотите также исправить его Uncorrect error на Incorrect ;)

Comment: @0andriy А смысл?... :)